# Assume-role "Access denied" for non-priveleged users of EC2-instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an EC2 instance that has been granted the ability to assume a role in another AWS account via IAM policies and an instance role applied to the EC2 instance. I am assuming the role using the AWS cli and the aws sts assume-role command. The instance is running RHEL 7.8 and I can successfully assume the role if I su to the root user first. However if I run the command as a local non-priveleged user (ec2-user is one example, but it does not work for other local users either).

What's odd is, the error message sounds like my system does not have the necessary IAM permissions, and does not seem related to the local user:

```
[ec2-user@instance --]$ aws sts assume-role -role-arn "arn:aws:iam:xxxxx:role/destination_role_name" --role-session -name "blah" 

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRoIe operation: User:arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/my-local-instance-role is not authorized to perform: Sts:AssumeRoIe on resource: arn:aws:iam:xxxxx:role/destination_role_name
```

I'm not sure what is missing that is causing the error. This exact same command works without issue if I'm su'd to the root user.

Edit: I wanted to add that I do not have any local config files set up that specify anything other than the AWS region. When I run the commands aws sts get-caller-identity or aws configure list, I confirm that I am showing up as the EC2 role as both root and the non-priveleged user.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the issue, and it's a weird one. It turns out I had a space in my command, and yet it still worked as root. The command was not spelled out in this post because I had heavily redacted things, but here's a new example showing the difference in case others ever run into this:

This works as root only. It gives an accessdenied if run as a non-privileged user:

`aws sts assume-role -role-arn "arn:aws:iam:xxxxx:role/role-name-that-ends-in -servicerole" --role-session -name "blah"`

Notice the -servicerole in the destination role ARN. It has a name that ends in -servicerole, but I somehow had a space in there and yet it still worked as root. I wonder if I was inadvertently setting some kind of Linux-based variable. Anyways, this is the command that did work:

`aws sts assume-role -role-arn "arn:aws:iam:xxxxx:role/role-name-that-ends-in-servicerole" --role-session -name "blah"`